# dhtmlxScheduler - Using Roles in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dhtmlx

I have dhtmlxScheduler working well with recurring events and events coloured according to type. However, I cannot understand how to limit the maintenance of the scheduler to those Users in a particular ASP.NET Role. I am trying to use the Save view but I cannot refresh the scheduler to remove any invalid input if the User is not in the required Role.

Has anybody managed to get this working successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simpler than I thought. The way to do it is in the `function init() {...}` routine, as follows:-

```
<% if ( User.IsInRole("EditEvents") ) { %>
    scheduler.config.readonly = false;
<% } else { %>   
    scheduler.config.readonly = true;
<% }; %>
```

Hope this helps anyone using dhtmlxSheduler.